# grafana / collectd Write Graphite plugin change timestamp

Tags: mysql, graphite, collectd, grafana

I am using collectd with write_graphite plugin to monitor mysql.
I am using EDT on my server and when creating dashboards on grafana I can only use UTC/browser time.

I want to know if there is an option to display the mysql server time (EDT)  on grafana? 
Any option to set offset time from UTC on the data samples the collect d is doing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end was to send the time stamp from the server as char:
SELECT 'server-time' AS category, CAST(TIME_FORMAT(CURTIME(), '%H.%i') AS CHAR) AS VALUE

In grafana edited the metric to get only the max value:
system.mysql_db.gauge-server_time-server-time:max

Also in singlestat type in grafana under options tab:
unit=short
decimals=2
big value->value=current